# How to check the installed version of React-Native

Tags: react-native

I'm going to upgrade react-native but before I do, I need to know which version I'm upgrading from to see if there are any special notes about upgrading from my version.

How do I find the version of react-native I have installed on my Mac?

Answer (score 198, accepted):

To see what version you have on your Mac(Window also can run that code.), run `react-native -v` and you should get something like this:

[image]

If you want to know what version your project is running, look in `/node_modules/react-native/package.json` and look for the `version` key:

[image]

Comment: Can I check package.json of the project root folder (not node_module)  to check the version there is also a key value like **"react-native": "0.49.3"**

Comment: Huh, so many upvotes, don't u guys get the error after running the command above.

Answer (score 57):

The best practice for checking the react native environment information.

```
react-native info
```

which will give the information

```
React Native Environment Info:
System:
  OS: Linux 4.15 Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS (Bionic Beaver)
  CPU: (8) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3770 CPU @ 3.40GHz
  Memory: 2.08 GB / 7.67 GB
  Shell: 4.4.19 - /bin/bash
Binaries:
  Node: 8.10.0 - /usr/bin/node
  Yarn: 1.12.3 - /usr/bin/yarn
  npm: 3.5.2 - /usr/bin/npm
npmPackages:
  react: 16.4.1 => 16.4.1 
  react-native: 0.56.0 => 0.56.0 
npmGlobalPackages:
  react-native-cli: 2.0.1
  react-native: 0.57.8
```

Comment: This is the one that works for me. The `-v` command doesn't work. This `info` command took quite long time to finish though.

Answer (score 42):

If you want to `see` which version of `react-native`, `react` or another one you are running, open your `terminal` or `cmd` and `run` the desired command

```
npm view react-native version
0.63.4
npm view react version
17.0.1
npm view react-scripts version
4.0.1
npm view react-dom version
17.0.1
```

[image: see my terminal]

Comment: This is the best answer!

Answer (score 39):

You can also open your `package.json` file in `node_modules` -> `react-native`.

The version is at the top:

```
 {
  "name": "react-native",
  "version": "0.12.0",
  ...
 }
```

Comment: I don't think this is true, `react-native -v` returns `0.48.4` while my `package.json` says `0.1.0`.

Comment: it actually true. react-native and react-native-cli are different things. @paulvs

Answer (score 19):

this works for me

`npm view react-native version`

Output is: 0.63.4

`npm view react version`

17.0.1

`npm view react-scripts version`

4.0.1

`npm view react-dom version`

17.0.1`

Answer (score 16):

Move to the root of your App then execute the following command,

```
react-native -v
```

In my case, it is something like below,

```
MacBook-Pro:~ admin$ cd projects/

MacBook-Pro:projects admin$ cd ReactNative/

MacBook-Pro:ReactNative admin$ cd src/

MacBook-Pro:src admin$ cd Apps/

MacBook-Pro:Apps admin$ cd CabBookingApp/

MacBook-Pro:CabBookingApp admin$ ls
MyComponents        __tests__       app.json        index.android.js    
ios         package.json
MyStyles        android         img         index.ios.js        
node_modules
```

Finally,

```
MacBook-Pro:CabBookingApp admin$ react-native -v
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.44.0
```

Comment: for, mac I use $ ./node_modules/.bin/react-native --version in the project folder

Comment: Yeah, that's also fine. The process of manual check by looking into installation directory `node_modules`.

Answer (score 11):

To see the local packages installed in your project including their versions and without their dependencies, run the below command from the project's root directory. In a React native app this would include the react-native package.

```
npm list --depth 0
```

Or if you installed them with yarn:

```
yarn list --depth=0
```

And to get just a specific package:

```
npm list react-native --depth 0
yarn list --pattern react-native --depth=0
```

Answer (score 7):

Find out which react-native is installed globally:

```
npm ls react-native -g
```

Answer (score 7):

If you are using `npx` you can run:

```
npx npm view react-native version
```

Answer (score 3):

Another option for checking react-native version with npx is :

```
npx react-native info
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have installed "react-native" globally then just open terminal/command line tool and type `react-native -v` you will get your answer.

And if you have installed "react-native" for a specific project then open terminal/command line tool and then navigate to your project and type `react-native -v` you will get your answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can run this command in Terminal:

> react-native --version

This will give react-native CLI version

**Or** check in package.json under

```
"dependencies": {
    "react": "16.11.0",
    "react-native": "0.62.2",
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I know 2 ways to test react-native version

1. Open **cmd** and type '**react-native --v**' or '**react-native --version**'
2. Open your project and open **package.json** file. U will see react-native version

Answer (score 2):

To know the react native version, just type this command below.

```
npx react-native -version
```

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure **npm** is installed on your system.
Use:  `[sudo] npm install npm -g` to download and install it.

Answer (score 1):

If you installed react native **globally**, on your terminal type:

```
  react-native --version
```

But if you installed without the global flag **-g**, type:

```
 npx react-native --version
```

**Or**

```
 yarn react-native --version
```

(If you have yarn installed)

Answer (score 1):

Just open the below file in your project :-

> package.json

under `dependencies` object you will get the version of `react-native`

Answer (score 0):

Just Do a "npm audit" on your project directory and then go to your project package.json file.
In the package.json file you will find all the versions and the package names.This should work irrespective of the OS.

Answer (score 0):

**You have two option**

1. run in cmd or Terminal

```
react --version
react-native --version
```

2. check in the project files, open the `Package.json`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check your **Package.json** file to know react-native version.

OR

Open terminal and run command **react-native -v**

Answer (score 0):

react-native
Usage: bin  [options]

Options:
  --version                     Print CLI version
  --verbose                     Increase logging verbosity
  -h, --help                    output usage information
**react-native --version** use this command

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed `"react-native"` globally then just open your terminal and use `react-native -v` to get the version installed on your pc.

Comment: Hi, how do you install `react_native` globally?

Answer (score 0):

To see what version you have on your Mac terminal, run **react-native --version** and you should get something like this: